# Confusion regarding the difference and thus the relation between Center of a group and Centraliser of an element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First of all, I would like to apologise if this has been asked before but I have not found any answer to any question answer my doubt.
This is embarassing considering I am beginning to study Sylow's Theorems yet can't distinguish between such concepts.

My question: Center of a group is the set of elements of the group commuting with every element of the group meanwhile the Centraliser of an element is the set of all elements commuting with the element, then how come the center is a subset of the Centraliser?

Comment: If $g$ is in the center and $x$ is in the group then $gx=xg$ (because $g$ is in the center) so $g$ is in the centralizer of $x$. QED.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your efforts to prove this, and make clear what stops you.

Answer (score 2):

You see, if $g$ is an element of some group $G$, and $x$ belongs to the center of the group, then by definition $xg=gx$, because $x$ commutes with every element of $G$, in particular, with $g$. But the equation $xg=gx$ also entitles $x$ a membership in the centralizer of the element $g$, right? Therefore, the center of the group is a subset of every centralizer.

Another way to think of it is as follows: the center of a group is the intersection of all the centralizers, and in particular, is contained in each of them.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I mean, the elements of center commute with all the elements of the group while the elements of Centraliser commute only with one element of a group. Am I wrong?

Comment: @StrugglingMathematician -- You are not terribly wrong, but somewhat inaccurate. The elements of a centralizer of $g$ are guaranteed to commute with $g$, but some of them may also commute with other elements, so it is not correct to say that they commute only with one element.